# How to find actual min API level supported by android project?

Tags: android, scala, intellij-idea, android-sdk-plugin

The `minSdkVersion` is manually set by the developer. But you can easily use a function at a higher level and not find out about it until runtime on a device that doesn't support it.

Is there a tool or compiler option that will warn you when you use a function that isn't supported by your `minSdkVersion`?

I'm using SBT, Scala language, and IntelliJ IDEA. Also using `android-sdk-plugin` for SBT.

EDIT:  I see a difference between my project (written mostly in Scala) and a default Java android app.  In the Java code, I get errors when trying to use functions that exceed the `minSdkVersion`. But in the Scala project the IDE and SBT build system both don't seem to care at all.  I suspect I'm missing a setting in my `build.sbt` file via `android-sdk-plugin`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Android Studio does that

Comment: As does Eclipse.  It generally comes as a warning not an error though-  because you may want to use those higher level functions on devices that do support it and either not support the feature or do it differently on lower level devices.

Comment: I think you have to specifically turn `abortOnError` option for lint when debugging

Comment: I'll look into `abortOnError`, although it looks like it's Gradle-specific? I'm not using Gradle, I'm using SBT. I do get warnings for deprecated functions, but not for functions that are of a higher api level than my minSdkVersion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API level check is performed by a [lint tool](http://tools.android.com/recent/lintapicheck) which is part of the Android SDK. The lint tool works on a Java AST and cannot do anything about code which is written in a different language. To have these checks work for Scala code, someone would need to write an equivalent tool for Scala, but I'm not aware of the existence of any such tool.